# Is there a Fluid viewhelper to truncate an URL? If not, how do I make one?

Tags: typo3, fluid, view-helpers, typo3-6.1.x

In TYPO3's Fluid or in Fedext/vhs, is there a viewhelper that can convert

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

into

```
www.stackoverflow.com
```

?

PS: that's the goal:

```
<f:format.raw><f:link.external uri="{item.link}">{item.just-display-the-domain}</f:link.external></f:format.raw>
```

EDIT (adapting the question to the answer I got): If I have to build a custom view helper, how do I proceed?

Comment: Why won't you write custom ?

Comment: If it's not there, I'll try. I'm just getting into fluid and try to find my way around. Does it have to be a custom view helper, or is there another way to slip in some php into the view part?

Comment: Actually now we have two popular branches of TYPO3 - 4.x and 6.x - tag your questions properly to make it always clear

Comment: Shouldn't the tag for 6.1.x be typo3-6.1 ? Maybe you want to create the proper one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really doubt if there would be any sensible reason for adding this kind of VH into the core, de facto, writing custom VH is like a piece of cake (when you finally realize it is) so simple formatters can be created by devs in their custom tool exts just in minutes.

Ie. in TYPO3 `4.x` assuming that you have a custom extension with key `urs` all you need to do is create one proper class, containing `render($params)` method and extending `Tx_Fluid_Core_ViewHelper_AbstractViewHelper` class:

`/typo3conf/ext/urs/Classes/ViewHelpers/GetDomainViewHelper.php`:

```
<?php
class Tx_Urs_ViewHelpers_GetDomainViewHelper extends Tx_Fluid_Core_ViewHelper_AbstractViewHelper {

    /**
     * @param $link string Each `allowed` param need to have its line in PHPDoc
     * @return string
     */
    public function render($link) {
        $link = str_replace('http://', '', $link);
        $link = str_replace('https://', '', $link);
        $segments = explode('/', $link);
        return trim($segments[0]);
    }
}
?>
```

Next in your templae declare its namespace and... that's all, you can use it:

```
{namespace urs=Tx_Urs_ViewHelpers}

<urs:getDomain link="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499453" />
```

Take special attention about letter case in things like `Tx_Urs_ViewHelpers...` etc.

More details in http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/8-Fluid/8-developing-a-custom-viewhelper.html

### In TYPO3 ver. 6.x

Things works preaty similar the main change of course is new namespacing

`/typo3conf/ext/urs/Classes/ViewHelpers/GetDomainViewHelper.php`:

```
<?php
namespace TYPO3\Urs\ViewHelpers;

class GetDomainViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper {

    /**
     * @param $link string Each `allowed` param need to have its line in PHPDoc
     * @return string
     */
    public function render($link) {
        $link = str_replace('http://', '', $link);
        $link = str_replace('https://', '', $link);
        $segments = explode('/', $link);
        return trim($segments[0]);
    }
}
```

In templates:

```
{namespace urs=TYPO3\Urs\ViewHelpers}

<urs:getDomain link="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499453" />
```

Of course in both cases instead of using hardcoded links you will use:

```
<urs:getDomain link="{item.link}" />
```

Comment: Ach just forgot to add - copying existing core VH's and modifying it in own implementations often allows to save tons of minutes ;)

Comment: One more question about the namespacing. In the extension builder, I chose a custom namespace MYFIRM\Extensionname - that's fine too, isn't it? Or would you stick with the TYPO3 Namespace?

Comment: Just use `{namespace urs=MYFIRM\Extensionname\ViewHelpers}` (also in VH's class!) instead ;) personally I prefer to use own vendorname, anyway for _safety_ wrote sample with default one.

Comment: Note: you must not use the TYPO3 namespace in your own extensions. It is very unfortunate that the extension_builder extension does this by default, but it is clearly stated on the "namespace migration guide" (for which I misplaced the link).

Answer (score 2):

It's a little bit cumbersome and not very efficient, but it should work and would of course prevent the need for a custom ViewHelper class:

```
With protocol:
{url -> v:iterator.explode(glue: '/') -> v:iterator.slice(length: 3) -> v:iterator.implode(glue: '/')}
Without protocol:
{url -> v:iterator.explode(glue: '/') -> v:iterator.slice(start: 2, length: 1) -> v:iterator.first()}
```

Where `{url}` can come from anywhere, as long as it contains a full `http://` or other protocol prefix. The line above of course explodes the URL into parts separated by `/` then slices off the first three segments and re-joins those using `/`. Or it simply picks offset `2` (which would be the full domain without protocol) and returns that single element. The result should be an url to the domain of the link, with or without protocol, without trailing slash (which you may or may not want to add yourself after cutting the URL).

Cheers,
Claus

Answer (score 0):

All ViewHelper are located at `typo3/sysext/fluid/Classess/ViewHelper`. There are also examples in the header of each file. All ViewHelper of Fedext can be reviewed on the [website](https://fedext.net/viewhelpers.html).