# Remove trailing slash in path created by the ImageViewHelper

Tags: typo3, fluid, view-helpers

I am trying to add CSS code to a template file using Fluid. I want to render a background-image uploaded at `/fileadmin/user_upload/foo.jpg`
However, `{images.0.url}` returns the path `/fileadmin/user_upload/foo.jpg/`
with a trailing slash, which then of course throws the following error:

> TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Exception
>
> Supplied file object type TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Folder for must be File or FileReference.

How can I remove the trailing slash from the path?

Below, the relevant code snippet is shown. Please note that `v:format.prepend` is just used for debugging purposes here and has no effect on the issue.

```php
    <f:section name="Header">
        <v:page.resources.fal table="pages" field="media" uid="{page.uid}" as="images" slide="-1" >
            <v:asset.style name="header">
                header#header <f:format.raw>{</f:format.raw>
                background-image: url(<f:uri.image src="{v:format.prepend(add: '', subject: '{images.0.url}')}" treatIdAsReference="1" />)
                <f:format.raw>}</f:format.raw>
            </v:asset.style>
        </v:page.resources.fal>

        <f:render section="Default"  partial="DefaultHeader" arguments="{_all}"/>
    </f:section>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20506132/5300921 possibly something like this? Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you think about the following?
You can remove the wrapping vhs ViewHelper and access the first media directly.

```
<v:asset.style name="header">
                header#header <f:format.raw>{</f:format.raw>
                background-image: url({f:uri.image(image:data.media.0})
                <f:format.raw>}</f:format.raw>
            </v:asset.style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar problem. Solved it by using absolute URLs of images. In my case it was (get URL):

```
<f:variable name="mediaUrl">{f:uri.image(image: mediaObject, treatIdAsReference: 1, absolute : 1)}</f:variable>
```

Later using URL as source:

```
data-src="{f:uri.image(src: mediaUrl, treatIdAsReference: 0)}"
```

I was switching sources between a provided obj and static resource uri based on condition, so this was necessary and came handy.